# REST - Api design for posting a form data and fetching another resource

Tags: rest, post, get, api-design, forms, http-post

I am developing a feature, where a user requests some data by filling a form and posting it. The form contains user details (name, email, mobile etc.) and these details need to be saved in the database as a lead. Once the lead data is saved successfully then only the requested data will have to be retrieved from the database and shown to the user.

I started looking into this problem by dividing it into below two APIs and calling it sequentially

1. A POST API to create a lead resource.
2. A GET API to fetch the requested resource on the success of POST.

But then I realized that the solution will affect the speed of data retrieval as I will be doing two separate network request sequentially and I cannot compromise on speed.

How can I solve this problem without compromising on speed? Should I use POST request and return the requested data in its response?

P.S. I cannot call both the APIs in parallel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly what you should do - the POST request should respond with the newly created resource, that the client can subsequently use.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the I first fire POST and then GET from my client? If yes, wouldn't it hamper the speed of data retrieval? Just to clarify, GET request will not use the newly created resource. POST and GET will be working on separate resource

Comment: I'm saying you should use the response received from your `POST`, not a separate `GET`

Answer (score 1):

You have been thinking about the problem from the web developer's perspective. You have this byte stream and to send it to clients doesn't need any form submission, a GET request ought to suffice. But from the business' perspective, retrieving the file does require a form submission, namely, the user's personal data. Even from the user's perspective it is a single operation. The user sends in the requisite data in order to get out the desired response (e.g. a file download). The saving of the input data (user's private details) is a side effect, not a user-intended outcome.

As such, a single POST request which submits the user data, saves it, then responds with the requested resource, is sufficient to cover the situation.